# Beautiful Soup and Selenium not grabbing content

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab some data from apartments.com but it seems as though BeautifulSoup alone will not capture the data because it's dynamic. After doing some research I've concluded Selenium is the way to get dynamic content to load.

However, even after using Selenium I'm not getting the relevant listings details.

This is what I have thus far:

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import folium
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from selenium import webdriver

'''Due to the site using  dynamic content ie Javascript, we cannot use BS4 by it's self. 
We will need to use Selenium

Step 1: Download driver: https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/
Step 2: Move driver where python script is located (just my preference)

'''


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/mikelowry/python/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.apartments.com/apartments-condos/san-francisco-ca/2-bathrooms/?sfmin=900'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html), 'html.parser')
```

This is what is being returned:

```
o\":false}]|37.7787|-122.41263|0~k9mxqp8|1|null|37.7787|-122.44426|2~cjkjj6g|5|null|37.77869|-122.41407|0~mnjp6ch|1|null|37.77867|-122.43304|2~44qs0fj|1|null|37.77866|-122.48541|2~sx7mfj6|1|null|37.77864|-122.49353|2~26wbtnb|6|null|37.77863|-122.39182|0~be9bv09|1|null|37.77859|-122.48809|2~js4dcl4|1|null|37.77858|-122.44505|2~cmh6fnf|1|null|37.77846|-122.4353|2~6bzrkdt|1|null|37.77842|-122.44616|0~5wx0f4n|1|null|37.77821|-122.43366|2~rw425l2|1|null|37.77817|-122.42577|2~w7s0jwh|1|null|37.77816|-122.48857|2~k2hwlz8|1|null|37.77811|-122.46602|2~xv9m1bp|1|null|37.77811|-122.40336|2~2897nbc|5|null|37.77809|-122.40446|0~fghxrnr|3|null|37.77802|-122.39746|0~qwlhlbz|1|null|37.77799|-122.42352|2~gk6sh8z|1|null|37.77792|-122.45077|2~c4vfj9g|1|null|37.7779|-122.45495|2~9x22j34|6|null|37.77789|-122.41125|0~w3ww5vk|1|null|37.7778|-122.4325|2~32sh4lf|3|null|37.77773|-122.41833|0~h9whkb3|1|null|37.77768|-122.39389|2~yvhnq3t|1|null|37.77748|-122.4752|0~2ljb10c|1|null|37.77723|-122.39558|2~8pdvlx3|5|null|37.77719|-122.41924|0~q5hfn6z|1|[{\"ListingId\":\"q5hfn6z\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false},{\"ListingId\":\"j14g4d4\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false}]|37.77719|-122.3934|0~et95plq|3|null|37.77714|-122.41521|0~mtq3q7k|1|null|37.7771|-122.43176|2~r5pt1x0|6|null|37.77705|-122.4386|0~m3sfkmk|6|[{\"ListingId\":\"m3sfkmk\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false},{\"ListingId\":\"pzp87br\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false}]|37.77703|-122.39574|0~m55rp3l|1|null|37.77702|-122.43174|0~qyzwp2y|1|null|37.7768|-122.4396|2~sz62h77|3|null|37.77674|-122.41833|0~yv6dh0t|5|null|37.77666|-122.41928|0~p067b0s|1|null|37.77655|-122.45888|2~zhk5v7w|6|null|37.77654|-122.46536|0~3xd65bf|1|null|37.77648|-122.43958|2~0x3mrn2|1|null|37.77644|-122.41|2~pxw0s0v|5|null|37.77642|-122.39324|0~f3f1xxv|1|null|37.77632|-122.40988|2~skc6084|1|null|37.77629|-122.40989|0~1bgn3l4|1|null|37.77624|-122.46748|0~bgygb0c|1|null|37.77624|-122.42265|2~q3kpqhy|6|null|37.77617|-122.45677|0~lnpl95g|1|null|37.77611|-122.40894|2~8z5g891|5|null|37.77601|-122.41726|0~rvn0jh1|1|null|37.77594|-122.44352|0~8jkle30|3|null|37.77577|-122.40959|0~sbphbh4|1|null|37.77566|-122.43101|2~5rkye5n|1|null|37.7755|-122.43206|2~edlwkhn|1|null|37.77543|-122.49928|2~pvvqedr|1|null|37.77543|-122.39055|2~twyb3pc|1|null|37.77534|-122.43136|2~s308n15|1|null|37.77528|-122.41144|0~jz19g67|1|null|37.77527|-122.43334|2~d5z6yyl|1|null|37.77525|-122.43475|2~lf5w8cd|6|null|37.77522|-122.44998|0~w5cp62h|1|null|37.775|-122.44664|2~49rn57j|5|null|37.77498|-122.40784|0~wdvfphh|1|null|37.77497|-122.42898|0~h8v5fr3|3|null|37.77493|-122.42527|0~0wlsy02|1|null|37.77485|-122.40045|2~ftbbtnr|1|null|37.77484|-122.39029|0~y0m4jjs|1|null|37.77479|-122.47011|2~5bc251p|1|null|37.77478|-122.41582|0~bn260q9|1|null|37.77474|-122.51091|2~8effbe1|6|null|37.7745|-122.48804|0~5t4qgsm|1|null|37.77423|-122.43287|2~f72z1vt|1|null|37.77418|-122.39474|0~58sk9dq|1|null|37.77401|-122.40478|2~7l08vty|5|null|37.77396|-122.39065|0~f51nh4s|1|null|37.77378|-122.47261|2~3rhd62e|1|null|37.77378|-122.47805|2~yjlxlwt|4|null|37.77366|-122.40947|0~52sddxp|5|null|37.77363|-122.41845|0~ej4prnp|1|null|37.77355|-122.43289|2~1rhl337|1|null|37.77352|-122.48989|2~j2x6nf5|1|null|37.77346|-122.4338|2~wqjf10k|1|[{\"ListingId\":\"wqjf10k\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false},{\"ListingId\":\"wm0blvj\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false}]|37.77342|-122.39591|0~s7zhp06|1|null|37.77334|-122.44495|2~ntfk15p|1|null|37.77321|-122.43511|2~923ywp4|3|null|37.77308|-122.39724|0~f4cv2pv|5|null|37.7729|-122.39252|0~2bevhs9|5|null|37.77288|-122.40575|0~8tkqj73|5|null|37.7728|-122.4195|0~1ybjl44|5|null|37.77247|-122.39691|0~plmhlcr|5|null|37.7723|-122.42191|0~gvp0zdw|1|null|37.77216|-122.44204|2~mkncvqk|1|null|37.77203|-122.50707|2~3x52nwf|5|null|37.77202|-122.40376|0~twv7jb8|1|null|37.77193|-122.3903|0~e65245m|4|null|37.77191|-122.42622|0~t0wweyc|6|[{\"ListingId\":\"t0wweyc\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false},{\"ListingId\":\"rhwd3r2\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false}]|37.77186|-122.4121|0~yr26w4t|6|null|37.77181|-122.39419|0~p3e6nqs|1|null|37.77164|-122.50762|2~cf4h0gg|4|null|37.7716|-122.42448|0~s2nmsd5|1|null|37.77159|-122.38859|0~m45wm0h|1|null|37.77147|-122.42137|0~y5dycer|1|null|37.77142|-122.44113|2~bzdysc8|4|null|37.77134|-122.39344|0~9c5t4h7|1|null|37.77116|-122.38903|0~61py1xs|1|null|37.77087|-122.45358|2~lqj4g6g|6|null|37.77079|-122.42802|0~71w8mby|1|null|37.77061|-122.39069|2~ls2bhtd|1|null|37.7704|-122.42648|2~x4k2dsm|5|null|37.77038|-122.41323|0~wn2v3wl|5|null|37.77034|-122.40308|0~zem09sx|1|null|37.77015|-122.45087|0~h4ynmg3|1|null|37.76999|-122.45336|2~8hbyfq2|5|null|37.7695|-122.40348|0~em53yzq|1|null|37.76894|-122.42989|2~s1swjl7|4|null|37.76857|-122.42713|0~x1bzp0m|1|null|37.76852|-122.43808|2~5zzvrcm|1|null|37.7685|-122.42119|2~2m813q9|1|null|37.76822|-122.44902|0~95v10m5|5|null|37.76756|-122.42932|0~3b514sd|1|null|37.76742|-122.44583|2~d53k5sj|1|null|37.76711|-122.42751|2~3893n5f|1|null|37.76709|-122.44891|2~288d2lb|1|null|37.76708|-122.45278|0~c9cjr5f|5|null|37.76704|-122.39697|0~lwhhlfg|3|null|37.76699|-122.42041|0~9qe6je7|1|null|37.76686|-122.43363|2~79158yx|3|null|37.76652|-122.4308|0~n1m1khq|1|null|37.76646|-122.43358|2~7t7384w|1|null|37.76643|-122.42858|0~bhwr3jb|6|null|37.76631|-122.4459|0~5gn4fkm|1|null|37.76608|-122.45828|2~k15xrnb|5|null|37.76603|-122.40012|0~9w5h944|6|null|37.76602|-122.42854|0~z0f97my|1|null|37.76585|-122.4487|2~5rsredn|1|null|37.76549|-122.41778|2~0h8fqv2|1|null|37.76545|-122.43214|2~fhlpgkt|1|null|37.76525|-122.42176|2~klh7m58|1|null|37.76507|-122.45034|2~f7bxb4t|1|null|37.76495|-122.47906|2~0dswfk1|1|null|37.76477|-122.46874|2~ntdrxsp|1|null|37.76465|-122.46668|0~qnghvfw|1|null|37.76464|-122.46605|2~50fkbrm|1|null|37.7646|-122.40095|2~zlhhjdz|1|null|37.76455|-122.47581|2~698ew4v|6|null|37.76454|-122.44768|0~89twt30|1|null|37.7645|-122.43664|2~r1f7f22|1|null|37.76448|-122.47416|2~se7m105|1|null|37.76429|-122.43506|0~qkgyfyz|1|null|37.76428|-122.41577|2~6kggrgt|1|null|37.76408|-122.40329|0~2kn7d8b|1|null|37.76398|-122.44263|2~h518yw2|4|null|37.7638|-122.38838|0~g3clmcx|1|null|37.76374|-122.46385|2~b9k87rc|6|null|37.76371|-122.50475|0~yfe2rkr|1|null|37.76368|-122.43978|2~8vk7d72|5|null|37.76351|-122.40763|0~s8g2y54|6|null|37.7635|-122.41815|0~hhl4f82|1|null|37.76328|-122.38816|2~z7m8hsw|1|null|37.76318|-122.42798|0~b1rlv7c|5|null|37.76315|-122.39914|0~54eljtm|1|null|37.76311|-122.44618|2~c15njrg|1|null|37.7631|-122.42129|0~7ml8qpw|1|null|37.76294|-122.48162|2~b06zbf9|1|null|37.76293|-122.39392|2~dd5pjgh|1|null|37.76273|-122.49927|2~xgl2ffm|1|null|37.76258|-122.4017|2~2qbp8p8|1|null|37.76256|-122.39415|2~d0qskyl|1|null|37.76239|-122.48961|2~4yrk77j|1|null|37.76225|-122.38837|2~f64bhgs|4|null|37.76219|-122.39189|0~ek5klnn|4|null|37.76203|-122.38936|0~qw02npw|1|null|37.76189|-122.39877|0~378tm6d|1|null|37.76173|-122.40165|2~sqt6hr4|6|null|37.76172|-122.48428|0~z49re2z|6|null|37.76169|-122.42485|0~pcrex9t|1|null|37.76166|-122.43365|2~qsm0k0z|1|null|37.76165|-122.43004|0~b20xef9|1|null|37.7615|-122.4347|0~q78lfcx|5|null|37.76148|-122.4106|0~dt0vxdj|1|null|37.76138|-122.43525|0~8qhnm30|1|null|37.76128|-122.40448|2~fpbbvmv|1|null|37.76126|-122.41053|2~ldfch3d|1|null|37.76126|-122.42542|2~h9qg9h3|5|null|37.76122|-122.38809|0~jwd1337|1|null|37.76113|-122.47724|2~h2hn2g1|1|null|37.7611|-122.43814|2~sm6ktw7|1|null|37.76099|-122.4978|2~f9nl8qv|1|null|37.76097|-122.3987|2~d1ss46l|1|null|37.76096|-122.49032|2~ftc8pss|1|null|37.76093|-122.38891|2~ke66pk9|1|null|37.76085|-122.44568|2~bg99c18|6|null|37.76074|-122.41732|0~57xmjqn|1|null|37.76008|-122.42561|2~beg5nsc|1|null|37.76001|-122.47774|0~wgmevqj|1|null|37.7598|-122.38991|2~8bk5j22|1|null|37.75971|-122.43194|2~mp1w8fh|1|null|37.75949|-122.50895|2~kme32tc|1|null|37.75948|-122.40725|0~777vxgy|5|null|37.75946|-122.46242|0~6gtpler|5|null|37.75926|-122.39173|0~wv57lxh|1|null|37.75921|-122.5089|2~qyktxry|1|null|37.75916|-122.50838|2~5rw0v5m|6|null|37.75907|-122.40803|0~dh4ppsh|1|null|37.75904|-122.43069|2~h91xlr2|1|null|37.75889|-122.44518|2~6261cev|1|null|37.75876|-122.45992|2~xt3w8cn|1|null|37.75875|-122.43444|2~5tb6z7q|1|null|37.7587|-122.41562|2~y7fhd1v|1|null|37.75846|-122.43398|2~cj6cy8e|1|null|37.75844|-122.4203|2~bshgs99|1|null|37.75839|-122.40025|2~h9qmsj2|1|null|37.75824|-122.41435|2~z49jrgz|1|null|37.75805|-122.46238|2~vl6sebe|1|null|37.758|-122.42716|2~7dwq5jz|1|null|37.75783|-122.39458|2~5m2h8qm|1|null|37.75743|-122.4231|2~vp4mv6g|1|null|37.75742|-122.42288|2~xxrzy6p|1|null|37.75741|-122.42263|2~fjc4c2r|1|null|37.75732|-122.4414|2~k5cg489|6|null|37.75722|-122.38853|0~dphl7ek|1|null|37.75715|-122.4148|2~rnhsh73|1|null|37.75705|-122.40931|2~tp0ckt9|1|null|37.757|-122.50773|2~3gg6h5e|5|null|37.75697|-122.3947|0~00hbq53|6|[{\"ListingId\":\"00hbq53\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false},{\"ListingId\":\"mc8716j\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false}]|37.75697|-122.50861|0~9fjt184|1|null|37.75691|-122.44005|0~k4ey4jb|1|null|37.75669|-122.44366|2~sj43n84|1|null|37.75658|-122.40917|2~ldlr67d|1|null|37.75644|-122.39854|0~zm8ee8w|1|null|37.75631|-122.42163|2~pz5293t|1|null|37.75626|-122.46609|0~09vdj41|4|null|37.75592|-122.38867|0~2mfzxb8|1|null|37.75555|-122.44387|2~zpb6elz|6|null|37.75547|-122.41524|0~9w8hks6|1|null|37.75546|-122.40039|0~tfxm4l8|1|null|37.75517|-122.4682|2~9852qy4|6|null|37.75497|-122.40901|0~79vx2hw|1|null|37.75472|-122.42792|2~36lphqg|1|null|37.75471|-122.41613|0~55vws6q|1|null|37.75451|-122.4196|2~z1z7tcx|1|null|37.75446|-122.47158|2~vkwvh9f|6|null|37.75434|-122.40131|0~8c3xjh3|1|null|37.75426|-122.42391|2~lqljwyd|1|null|37.75402|-122.42113|2~ejzlvvm|1|null|37.75378|-122.43464|2~f2rvy0t|7|null|37.75363|-122.44352|0~qcf15nw|1|null|37.75353|-122.49728|2~gp2dv0z|1|null|37.75346|-122.44167|2~yps79vr|1|null|37.7532|-122.42274|2~5vc5q3q|1|null|37.75303|-122.41282|2~k1rl139|1|null|37.75281|-122.39458|2~cwll81g|6|null|37.75231|-122.42075|0~vfbtjgg|1|null|37.75202|-122.41928|2~twhmqy8|1|null|37.75196|-122.44416|2~7th0dbz|1|null|37.75192|-122.42782|0~yh53frv|1|null|37.75178|-122.42871|2~5syhnrn|6|null|37.75168|-122.42767|0~9xw6yv7|1|null|37.75127|-122.41756|2~r2bbcz2|1|null|37.75109|-122.44037|2~setjcn5|1|[{\"ListingId\":\"setjcn5\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false},{\"ListingId\":\"8d2c9l1\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false}]|37.75106|-122.40671|0~ppwf2ns|1|null|37.75082|-122.42355|2~8yexrf3|1|null|37.75064|-122.41583|2~vm6mfpf|1|null|37.75042|-122.44288|2~0gnyfr0|6|null|37.75027|-122.41505|0~gf98c0w|1|null|37.7501|-122.44506|2~19554b7|1|null|37.74966|-122.4174|0~834lwz3|1|null|37.74938|-122.41466|2~8y1yyj3|1|null|37.74904|-122.42799|2~18x73r7|1|null|37.74888|-122.43853|0~s6q3t57|1|null|37.7487|-122.44434|2~f3fpvpv|1|null|37.74793|-122.42511|2~2se0r2c|1|null|37.74778|-122.4349|0~nfbtg2n|6|null|37.74695|-122.44113|0~ktjp4v9|1|null|37.74688|-122.41944|2~cvmzxtf|1|null|37.74674|-122.43275|2~gj098pw|1|null|37.74635|-122.41843|2~dbflnhj|1|null|37.74611|-122.42353|2~tnhwve9|1|null|37.74569|-122.4237|2~1gryec4|1|null|37.74557|-122.44302|0~j2jgm04|1|null|37.74514|-122.43298|2~dbgyvkl|1|null|37.74493|-122.44211|2~wc1vtyl|1|null|37.74456|-122.42327|2~3kfje2f|1|null|37.7437|-122.42145|0~2shxkkc|1|null|37.74316|-122.42561|2~0pj8962|1|null|37.74269|-122.47639|2~bvjkp4c|1|null|37.74231|-122.48817|0~mb4bezl|1|null|37.74228|-122.48693|2~phlsmws|1|null|37.74137|-122.4307|2~w048l1h|1|null|37.74085|-122.42201|2~c3t76yd|1|null|37.73991|-122.38866|2~vekl5cf|1|null|37.73882|-122.42836|2~p3m35ms|1|null|37.73806|-122.50277|2~tmfzbk8|1|null|37.73798|-122.41886|2~ge0s2hx|6|null|37.73778|-122.42369|0~sntchx7|1|null|37.73676|-122.4102|2~k53dysb|1|null|37.73576|-122.39194|2~eqglqfp|1|null|37.73541|-122.44377|2~zn6klhy|1|null|37.73531|-122.42695|2~s0jfdr5|1|null|37.73485|-122.39127|2~fnkgpfv|1|null|37.73475|-122.41775|0~p0dd63s|6|null|37.73466|-122.43305|0~yjqb99v|6|null|37.73465|-122.43304|0~3bj8nxe|1|null|37.73418|-122.4124|2~9z0hg74|1|[{\"ListingId\":\"9z0hg74\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false},{\"ListingId\":\"t3m5879\",\"Favorite\":0,\"IsTierTwo\":false}]|37.73342|-122.47099|0~el6y4bm|1|null|37.7325|-122.4351|2~5r1vf6p|1|null|37.73195|-122.40666|2~jyxz9j4|1|null|37.7309|-122.47235|2~987vm47|1|null|37.73085|-122.39725|2~cywm1ed|1|null|37.72808|-122.37172|0~5mfektm|6|null|37.7276|-122.36767|0~kwslmqb|1|null|37.72735|-122.36822|2~1qgp6s7|1|null|37.72726|-122.48061|2~jxqe0p5|6|null|37.72653|-122.46095|0~6zfvm5v|1|null|37.72646|-122.46095|0~d7dq4ll|1|null|37.72623|-122.46196|2~whrd6xj|1|null|37.72623|-122.46187|2~l6h75zd|1|null|37.72618|-122.46159|2~yfdtk5r|1|null|37.72616|-122.4615|2~qczbegy|1|null|37.72614|-122.4614|2~3z6t2vd|1|null|37.72611|-122.46131|2~t1kbfcb|1|null|37.72605|-122.46112|2~0qjxm50|1|null|37.72603|-122.46102|2~1yyls35|1|null|37.72534|-122.39931|0~vm1m9zg|1|null|37.725|-122.39606|2~l7w7epd|5|null|37.72477|-122.40029|0~613pgnt|1|null|37.72447|-122.45786|2~3bt2bkg|4|null|37.72397|-122.45554|0~9fdb5h5|6|null|37.72387|-122.4587|0~7bs5ggz|1|null|37.72318|-122.44135|2~dcg2rrh|1|null|37.72287|-122.40193|0~vkerlme|1|null|37.72219|-122.43949|2~gnb5kgz|1|null|37.72093|-122.48331|2~26ht3d9|5|null|37.72054|-122.47582|0~djygwgj|5|null|37.71789|-122.48383|0~220t5mb|1|null|37.71771|-122.44039|2~syegrl6|1|null|37.71709|-122.39656|2~wzzsn3h|5|null|37.7162|-122.49717|0~zkcwvny|1|null|37.71566|-122.44011|0~f40jq1t|1|null|37.71476|-122.47571|2~67g65bt|1|null|37.71409|-122.39826|0~tcfzhx8|1|null|37.71269|-122.44441|2~bt3jy49|1|null|37.71167|-122.41593|2~0pvmdb0|5|null|37.71154|-122.39166|0~xkfqlvm|6|null|37.71118|-122.38809|0~5qxlwvq|1|null|37.71112|-122.40409|2~1kdtfn7|1|null|37.7109|-122.42694|2~gp6brew|1|null|37.71073|-122.3902|2~ymk95mr|1|null|37.70984|-122.44915|2~hvdjll0|1|null|37.70796|-122.41299|2~mb68hdl|3|null|37.70753|-122.41593|0~c5txscg|1|null|37.7057|-122.46032|2~fqzywyt|1|null|37.7056|-122.46061|2~s6g2rn4|1|null|37.70354|-122.46736|2~sn7g025|3|null|37.70318|-122.46267|0~nepf56p|6|null|37.70097|-122.45847|0~zhse3tz|1|null|37.70061|-122.46387|2~5c72fdm|1|null|37.70033|-122.4579|0~rsdsj23|1|null|37.69987|-122.45751|0~8rh87l1|1|null|37.69965|-122.46575|2~vedq9qg|1|null|37.69953|-122.45965|2~7mdyx8x|1|null|37.69908|-122.46037|2~d23sjpl|5|null|37.6971|-122.48|0","TotalUnitCount":1327,"TotalNewCount":59,"ToExcludePins":false,"ResultTitle":"1,327 Apartments Available","OptionsTitle":"Options","MobileListingId":null},"PlacardState":null,"SearchCriteria":{"Map":{"Resolution":null,"BoundingBox":{"LowerRight":{"Latitude":37.70813,"Longitude":-122.35703},"UpperLeft":{"Latitude":37.86342,"Longitude":-122.51777}},"CountryCode":null,"Shape":null},"Geography":{"ID":"bdm1pg9","PlaceId":null,"Display":"San Francisco, CA","GeographyType":2,"Address":{"City":"San Francisco","County":null,"PostalCode":null,"State":"CA","StreetName":null,"StreetNumber":null,"Title":null,"Abbreviation":null,"BuildingName":null,"CollegeCampusName":null,"MarketName":"San Francisco","DMA":"San Francisco-Oakland-San Jose, CA"},"Location":{"Latitude":37.786,"Longitude":-122.437},"BoundingBox":{"LowerRight":{"Latitude":37.70813,"Longitude":-122.35703},"UpperLeft":{"Latitude":37.86342,"Longitude":-122.51777}},"O":null,"Radius":null,"v":19282},"Listing":{"MinRentAmount":null,"MaxRentAmount":null,"MinBeds":null,"MaxBeds":null,"MinBaths":2,"PetFriendly":null,"Style":5,"Specialties":null,"StudentHousingPricings":null,"StudentHousingAmenities":null,"StudentHousings":null,"Ratings":null,"Amenities":null,"MinSquareFeet":900,"MaxSquareFeet":null,"GreenCertifications":null,"Keywords":null,"MoveInDate":null},"Transportation":null,"StateKey":null,"Paging":{"Page":null,"CurrentPageListingKey":null},"SortOption":null,"Mode":null,"IsExtentLoad":null,"IsBoundedSearch":null,"ResultSeed":234414,"SearchView":null,"MapMode":null,"Options":1,"SavedSearchKey":null},"EncodedBoundingBox":null,"bs":{"br":{"ps":5,"bcs":[{"Text":"Home","Desc":null,"Url":"https://www.apartments.com/","ShouldRenderUrl":true,"GeographyType":null,"DataType":"apartments, condos"},{"Text":"California","Desc":null,"Url":"https://www.apartments.com/ca/","ShouldRenderUrl":true,"GeographyType":1,"DataType":"state"},{"Text":"San Francisco","Desc":null,"Url":"https://www.apartments.com/san-francisco-ca/","ShouldRenderUrl":true,"GeographyType":2,"DataType":"city"},{"Text":"San Francisco Apartments for Rent","Desc":null,"Url":"https://www.apartments.com/san-francisco-ca/","ShouldRenderUrl":false,"GeographyType":2,"DataType":"city"}],"ih":null}},"ffs":{"ffi":[{"ft":1,"fdb":[{"Id":1,"lc":13,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4,"lc":1077,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":8,"lc":87,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":16,"lc":414,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":32,"lc":9,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":64,"lc":110,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":128,"lc":32,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":2,"fdb":[{"Id":2,"lc":1017,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":1,"lc":976,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":3,"fdb":[{"Id":16,"lc":405,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":32,"lc":618,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4,"lc":737,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":524288,"lc":736,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":64,"lc":183,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":256,"lc":932,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":65536,"lc":1019,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":512,"lc":200,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":131072,"lc":455,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":2,"lc":759,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":1048576,"lc":35,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":2097152,"lc":267,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":128,"lc":300,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4194304,"lc":281,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":8388608,"lc":83,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":16777216,"lc":1,"u":null,"t":"Doorman"}]},{"ft":4,"fdb":[{"Id":2,"lc":0,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4,"lc":14,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":8,"lc":46,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":16,"lc":1030,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":5,"fdb":[{"Id":1,"lc":1193,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":2,"lc":92,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":16,"lc":18,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4,"lc":213,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":7,"fdb":[{"Id":3,"lc":69,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":2,"lc":1327,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":1,"lc":1728,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":-2,"lc":1728,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":6,"fdb":[{"Id":-1,"lc":44,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":1,"lc":18,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":2,"lc":1048,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":3,"lc":185,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4,"lc":32,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":-2,"lc":1327,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":10,"fdb":[{"Id":2,"lc":1077,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":9,"fdb":[{"Id":1,"lc":8,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4,"lc":1069,"u":null,"t":null}]},{"ft":8,"fdb":[{"Id":1,"lc":73,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":2,"lc":242,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":4,"lc":73,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":8,"lc":100,"u":null,"t":null},{"Id":32,"lc":17,"u":null,"t":null}]}]},"RemoveOutlineText":"Remove Outline","abd":[{"id":"","v":null,"et":17,"cdv":null,"cdi":17}],"Magicbar":{"Universities":[]},"FAQs":null,"SearchPriceMinimums":[1700,1800,2100,2500,2900,3500],"SearchPriceMaximums":[2400,2800,3200,3800,5000,5100]},
```

I'm expecting details about the listing:

i.e. Name: Parkmerced , Address:  3711 19th ave....

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `selenium` for this.

The entire search result comes in the source `HTML` as a `JSON` in a `<script>` tag.

Here's how to get the data:

```python
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
    endpoint = connection.get(
        "https://www.apartments.com/apartments-condos/san-francisco-ca/2-bathrooms/?sfmin=900"
    )
    script = BeautifulSoup(endpoint.text, "lxml").find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
    search_results = json.loads(script.string)
    for address in search_results["about"]:
        print(f"{address['name']} - {address['url']}")
```

Output:

```
150 Van Ness - https://www.apartments.com/150-van-ness-san-francisco-ca/8pdvlx3/
50 Jones - https://www.apartments.com/50-jones-san-francisco-ca/79rtqtx/
HQ - https://www.apartments.com/hq-san-francisco-ca/x4k2dsm/
The Madelon - https://www.apartments.com/the-madelon-san-francisco-ca/q78lfcx/
Avalon at Mission Bay - https://www.apartments.com/avalon-at-mission-bay-san-francisco-ca/pxw0s0v/
100 Van Ness - https://www.apartments.com/100-van-ness-san-francisco-ca/yv6dh0t/
Parkmerced - https://www.apartments.com/parkmerced-san-francisco-ca/26ht3d9/
2030 Vallejo Street Apartments - https://www.apartments.com/2030-vallejo-street-apartments-san-francisco-ca/khfjby8/
500 Folsom - https://www.apartments.com/500-folsom-san-francisco-ca/81mv0f0/
Bayside Village - https://www.apartments.com/bayside-village-san-francisco-ca/1rerqb5/
363 Sixth St - https://www.apartments.com/363-sixth-st-san-francisco-ca/2897nbc/
NEMA - https://www.apartments.com/nema-san-francisco-ca/8z5g891/
480-482 Potrero Ave - https://www.apartments.com/480-482-potrero-ave-san-francisco-ca/8vk7d72/
Jasper - https://www.apartments.com/jasper-san-francisco-ca/cgy0m0e/
33 Tehama - https://www.apartments.com/33-tehama-san-francisco-ca/eqzek7p/
399 Fremont - https://www.apartments.com/399-fremont-san-francisco-ca/vg7veyf/
One Henry Adams - https://www.apartments.com/one-henry-adams-san-francisco-ca/8hbyfq2/
Channel Mission Bay - https://www.apartments.com/channel-mission-bay-san-francisco-ca/7l08vty/
Waterbend Apartments - https://www.apartments.com/waterbend-apartments-san-francisco-ca/l7w7epd/
The Landing - https://www.apartments.com/the-landing-san-francisco-ca/3gg6h5e/
The Rise Hayes Valley - https://www.apartments.com/the-rise-hayes-valley-san-francisco-ca/plmhlcr/
1177 Market at Trinity Place - https://www.apartments.com/1177-market-at-trinity-place-san-francisco-ca/cjkjj6g/
Modera Rincon Hill - https://www.apartments.com/modera-rincon-hill-san-francisco-ca/b821swb/
Astella - https://www.apartments.com/astella-san-francisco-ca/2bevhs9/
Chorus - https://www.apartments.com/chorus-san-francisco-ca/8tkqj73/
```